# CoreData How to connect with relationship entity to another entity with already preloaded data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, relationship

This is my first application in CoreData so I definitely missing something here, but I spend over a week trying to find solution and apparently nobody on Internet had the same problem ;)

I'm creating something like deckbuilder app.:
My model looks like this: [coredatamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBd8R.png)

The relationship is to-one and inverse to-many ( every card can be in one set, and in every set can be many cards) from CARD to SET.

For sake of simplicity I want to focus on **CARD** and **SET** entities.
I preloaded data into SET from CSV file into 5 atributes - didnt fill relationship "karty" because I didn't know how to do this. There are about 25 records in this entity.

And now, problem is I am trying to fill CARDS Entity which will have over 500 records.
Trying few options I found on SO I end with connection that created 500 records in SET too:/ so it looked like sql "JOIN" command.

1. What I want is load data to CARDS and connect them somehow to SET not changing number of records in SET.
2. If i have `property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *karty;` what exactly NSSet means? It is s et but set of what? Set of single rows from Card entity? Set of Card objects? Set of NSStrings? Set of NSManagedObjects?

In normal SQL primary key to connect them would be "nazwaszort" so Card.nazwaszort=Set.nazwaszort.

My **Set.h**

```
  @class Card;

    @interface Set : NSManagedObject

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * cykl;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * czymajor;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nazwa;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nazwashort;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * nrwcyklu;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *karty;
    @end

    @interface Set (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

    - (void)addKartyObject:(Card *)value;
    - (void)removeKartyObject:(Card *)value;
    - (void)addKarty:(NSSet *)values;
    - (void)removeKarty:(NSSet *)values;

    @end
```

My **Card.h**

```
@class Frakcja, Kolekcja, Set;

@interface Card : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * czylimit;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * frakcja;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * icesila;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * iloscwsecie;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * influence;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * kodkarty;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * koszt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * minimumdecksize;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nazwa;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nazwasetu;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nazwaszort;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * nrcyklu;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * podtyp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * strona;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * trashkoszt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * typ;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Kolekcja *ilewkolekcja;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Frakcja *nazwafrakcji;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Set *wjakimsecie;

@end
```

I preloaded cards to SET using method

```
-(void) preloadDataPackInfoToDatabase {

    NSError *error=nil;

NSString *sciezka = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"nrsets" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:sciezka];
for (int i=1; i <=([rows count]-1); i++) {
        Set *nowyDataPack = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entityset name] inManagedObjectContext:_contextdp];
        NSLog(@"tablica wierszy %@",rows[i][2]);

        NSString *koddodatku = rows[i][2];
        NSLog(@"kod dodatku:%@",koddodatku);
        NSString *nrwcyklu = rows[i][4];
        NSString *nrcyklu = rows[i][3];
        NSString *nazwadatapack =rows[i][3];
        NSString *czymajor =rows[i][0];
[nowyDataPack setValue:nazwadatapack forKey:@"nazwa"];
        NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

        NSNumber *nrwcykluint = [f numberFromString:nrwcyklu];
        NSNumber *nrcykluint = [f numberFromString:nrcyklu];
        NSNumber *czymajorbool = [f numberFromString:czymajor];

        [nowyDataPack setValue:nrwcykluint forKey:@"nrwcyklu"];
        [nowyDataPack setValue:nrcykluint forKey:@"cykl"];
        [nowyDataPack setValue:koddodatku forKey:@"nazwashort"];
        [nowyDataPack setValue:czymajorbool forKey:@"czymajor"];

    }

    if (![ self.contextdp save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Nieznany błąd %@,%@",error,[error userInfo]);
    }

}
```

And another method (on pastebin to not flood your screens --> [preloadAllCardsToDatabase](http://pastebin.com/mw9rqhZS)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If this is your first application ever, it is good time to start naming your variables on english, brat :)

Comment: give more details about your csv

Comment: Well, not first app ever, rather first coredata ever, but I dislike using language that i am not native-speaker of in variables and methods :) I also  started naming my methods in polish, then exactly I know what function do what not wasting time to additional translation step in my mind;)

Comment: But returning to problem - It looks I need somehow get acces to specific row in SET entity and create array of Cards objects and at the end add this to NSSet.

Comment: you already have the access to the set object `Set *nowyDataPack`. You find all cards related to the set and add them to the `karty` NSSet

Comment: using this:  - (void)addKarty:(NSSet *)values; why not - (void)addKartyObject:(Card *)value;? Don't understand exactly the difference between these two.

Comment: In a core-data to-many relationship, the relationship is accessible through a property that returns an NSSet object.  The set will contain NSManagedObjects that are the entity specified in the relationship.  In your case, that's `Card*`.  `addKartyObject` is a convenience method that saves you having to get the set, create a mutable set, add your `Card` and update the property.

Comment: I'm starting to realize after writing whole bunch of code that it's not possible to load data to entity row-by-row and setting relationships at the same time. Now I get "failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)"

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally did it. Had to move some CoreData stuff outside loop.
Still dont understand this whole magic but at least it works.
for those interested this is my preloading function --> [here](http://pastebin.com/0nPynQ4A)